# Installing Laravel on Mac OS X Sierra

Tags: composer-php, laravel-5.3, macos-sierra

Hello I'm trying to install laravel using composer in my mac. But when I tried to move

> composer.phar

to `usr/local/bin` file. I found out that my local directory is empty! So where should I move

> composer.phar

so that I may use it in terminal.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved this problem by creating a new folder inside local named bin.

```
usr/local/bin
```

and moved

```
composer.phar
```

to that location.